# Python Regex to findall Delimited Substrings

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I have a string:

```
test2 = "-beginning realization 5 -singlespace -multispaceafter  not-this-one -whitespace\t\n -end"
```

I want a to find all of the substrings that begin with the minus sign (-).

I can find all "but" the last occurrence:

```
re.findall(ur"\B-(.*?)\s", test2)
```

returns `[u'beginning', u'singlespace', u'multispaceafter', u'whitespace']`

I can find "the last occurrence":

```
re.findall(ur"\B-(.*?)\Z", test2)
```

returns `[u'end']`

However, I want a regex that returns

> [u'beginning', u'singlespace', u'multispaceafter', u'whitespace', u'end']

Comment: no it should not match ;-singlespace only whitespace or empty space is allowed before the minus (-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code also,

```
>>> test2 = "-beginning realization 5 -singlespace -multispaceafter  not-this-one -whitespace\t\n -end"
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)-(\S+)', test2)
>>> m
['beginning', 'singlespace', 'multispaceafter', 'whitespace', 'end']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a non-capturing group to assert that either whitespace or the end of the string follows.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\B-(.*?)(?:\s|$)', test2)
```

Although, instead of `\B` and the non-capturing group I recommend the following:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\S)-(\S+)', test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\s)-(.*?)(?=\s|$)|(?<=^)-(.*?)(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cN7qZ7/6

Comment: It is returning 'this-one' and no part of 'not-this-one' should not be returned.

Comment: I ran this: `re.findall(ur"(?<=\s|^)-(.*?)(?=\s|$)", test2)`
I got this:
`Traceback: raise error, v # invalid expression
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: doesn't cover the case in which you have ;-singlespace. Visible characters in front of the minus sign should exclude the term.

Comment: @nueverest this voers all test cases.try now.

Answer (score 1):

The end doesn't match because you force a whitespace in the regex.

Try:

```
 # (?:^|\s)-(.*?)(?=\s|$)

 (?: ^ | \s )
 -
 ( .*? )
 (?= \s | $ )
```